# Chatbot is not working once created the Web App bot in Azure bot service

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I created a Web app bot in Azure portal. LUIS, App service, Insights got created automatically. This is a Basic bot using SDK-V4. It got created successfully. But after it when i tried to test the bot using "Test in Web Chat" it gave the "Failed to send activity: bot returned an error". I didn't even deployed any code for the bot.
PFB the screenshot of the issue below.

I just downloaded the bot source code and did some changes. It is working fine in Emulator by getting connected to LUIS. But in "Test using web chat" it is not working even with or without deployment of code.
I checked the following already:

1. Message Endpoints.
2. MS App ID and MS App Password in App service.

Actual getting results:

In App Insights:

```
Message : POST to SAP_Bot-DEV failed: POST to the bot's endpoint failed with 
          HTTP status 500 POST to the bot's endpoint failed with HTTP status 
          500.
Failed Message: Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI.ThrowOnFailedStatusCode

Call Stack:

Microsoft.Bot.Schema.BotException:
   at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__31.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
Inner exception System.Exception handled at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__31.MoveNext:
   at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI.ThrowOnFailedStatusCode (Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__31.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
```

In Browser:

```
{error: {code: "BotError", message: "Failed to send activity: bot returned an error"},…}
error: {code: "BotError", message: "Failed to send activity: bot returned an error"}

httpStatusCode: 500[In Browser][1]
```

[App Insights Screenshot[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzhnS.jpg)

Comment: It sounds like it cannot connect to your endpoint which makes me thing it was a deployment issue or has never been deployed. Does it work from the emulator if you enter the endpoint URL + App and and Pass from Azure? I would try downloading the bot source code then running the deployment script again. There should be a `Deployment/Scripts` folder with a `template-with-preexisting-rg.json` file in it. The instructions are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-basic-deploy?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Cerg#deploy-your-bot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved. Initially we created the MS application ID and password manually by creating an application in azure portal. There was some issue with the manually created ID, then we tried with automatic app ID creation (after getting required authorization in azure portal) and it works. Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Try publishing your bot and check if the messaging endpoint url is not set to localhost but to your published url in azure and in registration portal[set your messaging endpoint as the redirect url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpMTS.jpg)

Comment: I checked the messaging endpoint url and it is configured properly. Also while testing it in emulator it is working fine. But after deplyment it is giving above mentioned errors. I am even getting the same error while trying to test the bot with "Test in web chat" straight away after creating the web app bot in azure portal.

Comment: Does it happen if you create _another_/new web app bot in the azure portal? Or is it just a problem with this one bot?

Comment: For every bot it's giving the same error. I tried creating different bots.

Comment: Can you please check your app settings and see if your right app id and password are fed into your app settings.

Comment: Can you also check your endpoint in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/,  where you have registered your bot.

Comment: I checked the app ID and password registered for that app service and also the endpoint. Its configured correctly. We are creating the web app bot in azure portal in a tenant (Resource group) created for us in azure in Europe region. Will there be any issue on that? Have anyone faced issues while having a separate RG created in a tenant in azure?

Comment: I have edited my answer with an image,  set your endpoint url as the redirect url and then test in webchat.

Comment: @ElmaSarahDaniel Thanks for your reply. The redirect URL is configured correctly. Still no luck. Actually we have created the bot in a resource group in Azure (hosted in west europe). I dont think that is an issue, but is there any possibility for that? Because we have not deployed any code, just creating the web app bot and testing it using "Test in Web chat" option. Its not responding at that time itself..

Comment: Try creating a Web App Bot using the Echo template instead of Basic. Let me know if that works.